# Two filterrific forms for one result table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filterrific

Setting up filterrific was a breeze and it works perfectly fine, but now we want to do something more complicated and I can't seem to figure out how to best proceed:

In an application to manage Updates, we have Systems and Packages. Each Package has_many Package-Versions and each Package-Version can be associated (many-to-many via a ConcretePackageVersion) to Systems.

Now we want to have a view with **two** filterrific forms, one for the System and one for the Package, where the user can filter both ways and it'll **show packages** that have a connection to the filtered systems and pass the package filters as well.

My idea was to have the usual filterrific setup with the Packages and then add another filterrific form for the Systems which then influences the Packages' filters. The problem and my question is: ***How should the second form/filter influence the first form?***

Version:

```
$ gem list | grep filter
filterrific (2.0.5)
```

Here's my code so far:

CombinationsController

```
def index
  @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    Package,
    params[:filterrific],
      :select_options => {
        sorted_by: Package.options_for_sorted_by,
        with_package_group_id: PackageGroup.options_for_select
      }
  ) or return
  @packages = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])

  @filterrific_systems = initialize_filterrific(
    System,
    params[:filterrific],
      :select_options => {
        sorted_by: System.options_for_sorted_by,
        with_system_group_id: SystemGroup.options_for_select
      }
  ) or return
  @systems = @filterrific_systems.find.page(params[:page])
end
```

views/combinations/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific_systems do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field( :sys_search_query, class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed') %>
  # more fields
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field( :search_query, class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed') %>
  # more fields
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<div id="filterrific_table">
  <%= render(
    partial: 'combinations/list',
    locals: {
      packages: @packages,
      systems: @systems
    }
  ) %>
</div>
```

views/combinations/index.js.erb

```
<% js = escape_javascript(
  render(partial: 'combinations/list', locals: {
    packages: @packages,
    systems: @systems
    })
) %>
$("#filterrific_table").html("<%= js %>");
```

models/system.rb

```
  filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'registered_at_desc' },
    available_filters: [
      :sorted_by,
      :sys_search_query,
      :with_system_group_id
    ]
  )
  # scopes are pretty much the same as in the demo application
```

models/package.rb

```
filterrific(
  default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'name_desc' },
  available_filters: [
    :sorted_by,
    :search_query,
    :with_package_group_id
  ]
)
#more scopes here as well
```